# How can I get the current selected row for UIPicker?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

How can I get the current selected row for UIPicker?

I want to use it to get at the associated string. Like this. The problem is I do not know how to get the row.

```
//need to get currently selected row
 NSString *strPeriodSelection = [arrayRecurChoices objectAtIndex:periodPicker.row???];
```

Comment: Would be nice if you accepted some of the answers that you've received on this and other questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614369-selectedrowincomponent). Check out [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/8315-uipickerview-selected-item.html) discussion.

Comment: It could not find that method, not sure why.

Comment: Updated with link, to assure you that the method really exists.

Comment: I see now. The method begins with a lower class s. Thank you.